# If condition within for loop execution in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

1). 'A' is a tensor of shape [:,1] that contains n rows of elements. There are 3 unique elements in this 'A' tensor. Let us say the unique elements are A1, A2, A3.

2). Similarly, 'B' is a tensor of shape [:,1] that contains n rows of elements. There is the same number of unique elements as in tensor 'A'. Let us say these elements are B1, B2, B3.

3) I have initialized three variables C1, C2, C3.

I want to construct a new tensor 'D' of shape [:,1] in such a way that at whichever index A1 appears in A, I want B1*C1 at that particular index in tensor 'D'.

I do not know what to use here, tf_cond, tf_case?. Even the errors I encounter are looking complex.

Please let me know in which way I can construct the TensorFlow graph. The python code is attached below. In the below example, I want to initialize the C1, C2, C3 to some values such as 1.0, 1.5, 1.3.

```
import sympy as sp
A = [1,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,1]
B = [100,200,300,200,300,100,300,200,200,100]
C1 = sp.Symbol('x1')
C2 = sp.Symbol('x2')
C3 = sp.Symbol('x3')

def output_D(P,Q,i,j,k):
    D = []
    for loop in range(0,9):
        if P[loop] == 1:
            D.append(Q[loop]*i)
        elif P[loop]== 2:
            D.append(Q[loop]*j)
        else:
            D.append(Q[loop]*k)
    return D

print(output_D(A,B,C1,C2,C3))
>>[100*x1, 200*x2, 300*x3, 200*x2, 300*x3, 100*x1, 300*x3, 200*x2, 200*x2]
```

Comment: Hi ! do you have a working numpy version of what you are asking ? or even pure python?
Could you also share the attempts that you made so far?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I have edited my question. I am very new to TensorFlow and did not want to confuse myself by asking too many questions. Kindly, verify.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want to initialize the C1, C2, C3 to some values such as 1.0, 1.5, 1.3"? Does it mean that the output tensor should actually be a float tensor or do you want a string tensor?

Comment: I also don't understand the interest of doing all of that in tensorflow. Basically what you are doing is an element-wise multiplication of 2 tensors, B and A', where A' is the version of A with elements replaced from C. This replacement of elements is not going to be differentiable and therefore probably doesn't belong in a graph. Could you give a bit more context into what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The output D is the tensor which is an integral part of the loss function. Let us say K = DU (where U is an other tensor). So,the ultimate goal is to minimize this K by using optimizers. Once this loss is minimized, I want to obrain parameters C1, C2, C3 ( that is why I wanted  C1 , C2, C3 to be initialized as variables and not constants)

Comment: ok so A and B are input tensors and the derivative will be with respect to C and never to A or B ?

Comment: If it's the case then I would reorganize my tensors. Basically your output is kind of a tensor obtained from A and B, multiplied-element wise by C.
I will try to come up with something along these lines.

Comment: I am sorry if was not clear before. The data fed to the neural network comprises of A, B tensors in the feature space. The output is  (U-actual).

Comment: Yes I understand, I am saying that potentially you could feed in something different than A and B to the network and handle them differently in pure Python.